# WebAPI Routing - entirely dynamic urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to define two routes.  One is simply a get request to the web root, e.g. `http://localhost` and the second is a get request with one parameter, e.g `http://localhost/{sport`}.  I can get the 1st route working ok, but not the 2nd.  I have tried many variations.  This is one of them:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace PricingBridge.RestService
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "aRoute",
                routeTemplate: "{myParam}",
                defaults: new { controller = "My", myParam = UrlParameter.Optional });
        }
    }

    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "1";
        }

        public string Get(string myParam)
        {
            return "2";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web API nested routing not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595764/web-api-nested-routing-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `UrlParameter.Optional`, use `RouteParameter.Optional`.

Former is MVC and latter is Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Your routing configuration seems fine. 
Try to change `UrlParameter` to `RouteParameter`, when it doesn't help try to make your own controller selector for diagnostics, just for intercepting to see what controller calls there and .

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new MyControllerSelector(config))
```

or the same with action selector [IHttpActionSelector](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection). It will let you see what controller or actions are exactly selected for your calls.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong class.  I should have been defining the routes in WebApiConfig, not RouteConfig.

The solution for my requirements is as follows (ignore the return values):

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "{sport}", new { controller = "bridge", sport = RouteParameter.Optional });
        }
    }

    public class BridgeController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<RestItem> GetSports()
        {
            return new[] { new RestItem("sport1", "relation") };
        }

        public IEnumerable<RestItem> GetFixtures(string sport)
        {
            return new[] { new RestItem(sport + "/fixture", "relation") };
        }
    }
```